# Link picks to much information html/js

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on a word generator thats picks random words from a variable.
The picked word makes the url complete. `$('.modal-body').text();`
But when I click on it it picks the word + read more, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cycling_Read_more. (cycling is the picked word)

And for some reason `target="_blank"` isn't working

```
<a  class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small left" href="http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/"onclick="location.href=this.href+$('.modal-body').text();return false;" target="_blank">Read more</a></div>
```

Comment: please try to provide english version of link. And now your question is not clearly

Comment: What should be the desire result, without `_read_more`? And please post your `.modal-body`.

Answer (score 0):

If it includes "Read More" in the URL, then presumably the element with `class="modal-body"` includes that as part of its text.

It is ignoring the target attribute because you aren't following the link. You're assigning a new URL to the browser in JS and then returning false so the link isn't followed.